# How can i add two tables in excel csv file?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, export

I am creating excel CSV file using the following code its working fine for me generating the first image table.But i want to generate the CSV for the image second.Can anyone please tell me how can i add two tables in single file and how can i insert record where no heading of column and how can i add a emty row and column in excel csv?

[image]

```
CsvExport myExport = new CsvExport();
string fileName = "AbsentEmployeesReport" + Session["id"] + ".csv";
foreach (var item in lstEmployees)
{
myExport.AddRow();
myExport["Enroll ID"] = item.EnrollNumber;
myExport["Employee (Firt and Last)"] = item.Name;
myExport["Department"] = item.Department;
myExport["Absent Count"] = item.AbsentCount;
}
string myCsv = myExport.Export();
myExport.ExportToFile(Server.MapPath("/Reports/" + fileName), myCsv);

using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Simple CSV export
public class CsvExport
{
  /// <summary>
  /// To keep the ordered list of column names
  /// </summary>
  List<string> fields = new List<string>();

  /// <summary>
  /// The list of rows
  /// </summary>
  List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

  /// <summary>
  /// The current row
  /// </summary>
  Dictionary<string, object> currentRow { get { return rows[rows.Count - 1]; } }

  /// <summary>
  /// Set a value on this column
  /// </summary>
  public object this[string field]
  {
    set
    {
      // Keep track of the field names, because the dictionary loses the ordering
      if (!fields.Contains(field)) fields.Add(field);
      currentRow[field] = value;
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Call this before setting any fields on a row
  /// </summary>
  public void AddRow()
  {
    rows.Add(new Dictionary<string, object>());
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Converts a value to how it should output in a csv file
  /// If it has a comma, it needs surrounding with double quotes
  /// Eg Sydney, Australia -> "Sydney, Australia"
  /// Also if it contains any double quotes ("), then they need to be replaced with quad quotes[sic] ("")
  /// Eg "Dangerous Dan" McGrew -> """Dangerous Dan"" McGrew"
  /// </summary>
  string MakeValueCsvFriendly(object value)
  {
    if (value == null) return "";
    if (value is INullable && ((INullable)value).IsNull) return "";
    if (value is DateTime)
    {
      if (((DateTime)value).TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds==0)
        return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      return ((DateTime)value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
    string output = value.ToString();
    if (output.Contains(",") || output.Contains("\""))
      output = '"' + output.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
    return output;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Output all rows as a CSV returning a string
  /// </summary>
  public string Export()
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // The header
    foreach (string field in fields)
      sb.Append(field).Append(",");
    sb.AppendLine();

    // The rows
    foreach (Dictionary<string, object> row in rows)
    {
      foreach (string field in fields)
        sb.Append(MakeValueCsvFriendly(row[field])).Append(",");
      sb.AppendLine();
    }

    return sb.ToString();
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Exports to a file
  /// </summary>
  public void ExportToFile(string path)
  {
    File.WriteAllText(path, Export());
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Exports as raw UTF8 bytes
  /// </summary>
  public byte[] ExportToBytes()
  {
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Export());
  }
}
```

How can i generate excel CSV like following:
[image]

Comment: Create the first part of the CSV file first & then append the second part.
Blank lines are simply that - just a blank line in the file.
Empty cells can be created by adjacent commas.

Comment: It's not apparent to me what your incoming data looks like or how exactly you're loading it. However, in general, you don't need to think of it has headers and data. Just think of it as rows and columns. If you want to move to the next row, use `sb.AppendLine()` (basically adding a hard return). If you want to move to the next column, just add a comma to the StringBuilder before you add the data for the next cell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, CSV stands for comma separated values, if you open up your generated file through note pad you will have a real look what those data really looks like  and you will have an idea on what your asking for.

1. to insert empty row you just do "","","",""
2. To insert empty column (let's say, first column is empty) you do "","data1","data2"
3. to insert your new table 2, you do the same as creating your table1 but you insert your table heads first after the table1. so the data should like this:

column1-1,column1-2,column1-3
datat1-1,"data1-2,data11-3
column2-1,column2-2,column2-3
data12-1,data12-2,data12-3"
.....

Comment: How is it possible to understand that `column2-1,column2-2,column2-3` is the header of the second table, but not some data from the first one?